# Neo4Django - How to define relationships dynamically?

Tags: django, neo4j, neo4django, neomodel

I don't have static lists of nodes and relationships between them. Users will enter their own data to the db, along with relationships. For example, after registration they will have a person node with name and userid properties, and after adding their personal data, such as birth date, I will hold this information in separate nodes with relationship that the user will enter.

How can I achieve this with neomodels?